# Java - How to implement method clone for base and derived classes

Tags: java, clone

I have three classes:

```
Base extends Object

Derived1 extends Base

Derived2 extends Derived1
```

Each of the classes has its own fields which should be cloned. And I have troubles with understanding the best way to implement `clone` and avoid duplicating code. I have a the following architecture, but it looks like worst to me

`Derived2.clone()`: it calls `super.clone()` and receives an object of `Derived1`. Then it calls the new `Derived2(objOfDerived1)` which calls `super(objOfDerived1)` which copies all of its fields and after that in `Derived2.clone()` all the fields of `Derived2` are copied.

How would you say to this? Maybe there are any articles which describe this problem?

UPD: the idea can be shown here

```
class Base implements Cloneable {
    private String dataOfBase;

    public Base() {

    }

    public Base(Base base) {
        this.dataOfBase = base.dataOfBase;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        Base base = new Base();
        base.dataOfBase = dataOfBase;
        return base;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private String dataOfDerived;

    public Derived(Base base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        Base base = super.clone();
        Derived derived = new Derived(base);
        derived.dataOfDerived = dataOfDerived;
        return derived;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you clone a `Derived2`, your `super.clone()` will return a instance of `Derived2`, not a `Derived1` nor a `Object`.

Comment: Why do you first call ```super.clone()``` and call ```new Derived2``` afterwards? I would just call ```new Derived2(this);``` and implement the copying in the copy constructor. If you're not going to use ```Object.clone()``` any ways.

Comment: @JornVernee, yea, it might be more useful

Comment: @tkausl, why? It looks like that Derived1.clone() will be called and object of Derived1 should be returned

Comment: Not if you're using `Object`s clone method. `Object.clone()` _always_ returns a copy of the runtime type, even though it says it returns `Object`. So if you clone a `Derived2` you'll get a `Derived2`, even though `Derived1` says you'd get a `Derived1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement `clone` in terms of the copy constructor:

```
class Base {
    private String dataOfBase;
    ...
    public Base(Base other) {
        this.dataOfBase = other.dataOfBase;
    }

    @Override
    public Base clone() { // Covariant return type
        return new Base(this); // calling copy constructor
    }
}
```

```
class Derived extends Base {
    private String dataOfDerived;
    ...
    public Derived(Derived other) {
        super(other);
        this.dataOfDerived = other.dataOfDerived;
    }

    @Override
    public Derived clone() {
        return new Derived(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this. It would allow you to clone any class in the hierarchy directly and include the data from all classes higher in the hierarchy.

```
public class Derived1 extends Base {

   public Derived1 clone(Derived1 foo) {
      super.clone(foo);
      // copy fields from Derived1
      return foo;
   }

   public Derived1 clone() {
      Derived1 foo = new Derived1();
      return this.clone(foo);
   }

}
```